# Numerical versus analytical manipulation of function f[x,y]

Tags: plotting, function-construction

I am calculating a two variable function f[x,y] and then want to plot f[x,x]. When I define the function f[x,y] analytically the plot works fine but when I calculate the function through a numerical integral the transition from f[x,y] to f[x,x]  doesn’t work. In the numerical case one apparently needs to include a redefining step to get from f[x,y] to f[x,x] but I can’t figure it out.

```
Clear["Global`*"]

d = 1.;
s = d/3.2; 
nfac = 2*(Pi/d); 
q1 = p1*nfac; 
q2 = p2*nfac; 
phi = 1.; 

X = Integrate[
    phi/E^(I*(q1*y1 + q2*y2)), {y1, -d/2 - s/2, -d/2 + s/2}] + 
   Integrate[phi/E^(I*(q1*y1 + q2*y2)), {y1, d/2 - s/2, d/2 + s/2}]; 

G2[p1_, p2_] := 
  Abs[Integrate[X, {y2, -d/2 - s/2, -d/2 + s/2}] + 
     Integrate[X, {y2, d/2 - s/2, d/2 + s/2}]]^2; 

Abs[FindMaximum[{G2[p1, 
    p2], -(0.*5) <= p1 <= 0.5 && -0.5 <= p2 <= 0.5}, {p1, p2}]];

G0 = Extract[N[%], {1}];

Plot3D[G2[p1, p2]/G0, {p1, -2.5, 2.5}, {p2, -2.5, 2.5}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"q1", "q2", "G(2)(q1,q2)"}, PlotRange -> All, 
 ImageSize -> Medium, AspectRatio -> 1, 
   ColorFunction -> ColorData["CMYKColors"]]

f = {G2[p, p]/G0, G2[p, 0.01]/G0, G2[p, 1]/G0, G2[p, 2]/G0}; 

Plot[Evaluate[f], {p, -2.5, 2.5}, PlotRange -> All, 
 Exclusions -> None, PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue, Cyan}, 
 Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {" q", "pattern "}, 
   LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, 18], 
 PlotLegends -> {" G2[p,p]", "G2[p,0 ]", "G2[p,1]", "G2[p,2]"}]
```

Comment: The code you have supplied does not work. `G0` is not defined. `Abs[FindMaximum[{G2[p1, p2], -(0.*5) <= p1 <= 0.5 && -0.5 <= p2 <= 0.5}, {p1, p2}]]` produces errors. However, if these problems were fixed, I think defining `f` as `f[p_] = {G2[p, p]/G0, G2[p, 0.01]/G0, G2[p, 1]/G0, G2[p, 2]/G0}; ` and plotting with `Plot[f[p], {p, -2.5, 2.5}, ...]` might work.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that I missed a line that defines G0

Comment: I tried your definition of f[p_]   but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Even if you supply a value for `d` (which you didn't) you would get as far as plotting `G2[p1, p2]/G0` (producing [this plot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/lCQO6.png) ). After that you need to inspect and fix this `Table[Evaluate[f[p]], {p, -2.5, 2.5}]` using the definition m_goldberg supplied.

Answer (score 3):

I'm just going to make your code work with as few changes as possible, so that you get your answer. Note, however, that it can be written in a much more elegant and efficient way.

---

The main issue is that `p1` and `p2` were not set as local variables, so that `G2[p, p]` was independent on `p` because there were hanging `p1` and `p2`. Therefore:

```
d = 1.;
s = d/3.2;
nfac = 2*(Pi/d);
q1[p1_] = p1*nfac;
q2[p2_] = p2*nfac;
phi = 1.;
X[p1_, p2_] = 
 Integrate[
   phi/E^(I*(q1[p1]*y1 + q2[p2]*y2)), {y1, -d/2 - s/2, -d/2 + s/2}] + 
  Integrate[
   phi/E^(I*(q1[p1]*y1 + q2[p2]*y2)), {y1, d/2 - s/2, d/2 + s/2}]

G2[p1_, p2_] := 
 Abs[Integrate[X[p1, p2], {y2, -d/2 - s/2, -d/2 + s/2}] + 
    Integrate[X[p1, p2], {y2, d/2 - s/2, d/2 + s/2}]]^2

Abs[FindMaximum[{G2[p1, p2], -(0.*5) <= p1 <= 0.5 && -0.5 <= p2 <= 0.5}, {p1, p2}]];
G0 = Extract[N[%], {1}]
```

> 0.152588

```
Plot3D[G2[p1, p2]/G0, {p1, -2.5, 2.5}, {p2, -2.5, 2.5}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"q1", "q2", "G(2)(q1,q2)"}, PlotRange -> All, 
 ImageSize -> Medium, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 ColorFunction -> ColorData["CMYKColors"]]
```

[image]

Then

```
G2[p, p]
```

[image]

is indeed a function of `p`. And finally

```
f[p_] := {G2[p, p]/G0, G2[p, 0.01]/G0, G2[p, 1]/G0, G2[p, 2]/G0}

Plot[Evaluate[f[p]], {p, -2.5, 2.5}, PlotRange -> All, 
  Exclusions -> None, PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue, Cyan}, 
  Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {" q", "pattern "}, 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, 18], 
  PlotLegends -> {" G2[p,p]", "G2[p,0 ]", "G2[p,1]", "G2[p,2]"}]
```

[image]